# Octave packages

Tags: software-installation, octave

I am unable to install the `octave-image:i386` package. To solve this issue, I installed dependencies but I got the same error after that:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave-image:i386 : Depends: octave:i386 (>= 4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

Can anyone please help me regarding this issue?

```
pagla@pagla-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-cache policy octave octave-image
octave:
  Installed: 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1
  Candidate: 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.8.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
octave-image:
  Installed: 2.4.0-1~octave~trusty1
  Candidate: 2.4.0-1~octave~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.0-1~octave~trusty1 0
        500 "http:ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages"
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.0-3 0
        500 "http/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages"
```

Comment: [Edit the question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/851177/edit) and include the output of `apt policy octave octave-image` command

Comment: it showed "invalid operation policy"

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? If that doesn't work use `apt-cache policy octave octave-image` instead

Comment: it showed "invalid operation policy"

Comment: yup, ubuntu  14.04.

Comment: the output of this command is something like "octave:
  Installed: 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1
  Candidate: 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1 0
 " and some more information as well

Comment: add them to the answer

Comment: i have added them to answer, but i am unable to see that answer. Moreover i am new to Ubuntu and this forum as well.

Comment: Sorry. I meant question. Add the info to the question

Comment: Why did you remove the weblink? Was it a PPA? include all info

Comment: let me put complete output in question.

Comment: Also you seem to be using 64bit OS, why you need `i386` packages? Those are for 32bit

Comment: yup i am using 64 bit operating system,then which package i should install? Actually i want to install packages of image processing for octave .

Comment: You should just install `octave-image` without using `:i386` at the end of the package name

Comment: let me know if the above command worked

Comment: yup it worked, but my problem is not solved yet. The problem i am facing now is; in Octave i am unable to run a command "rgb2gray". and the reason behind this problem is that the packages related to image processing are not installed for Octave.

Comment: The package was installed correctly but i forgot to load it, now i just loaded that package and octave is working properly now. Thank you so much for spending your precious time :)

Comment: Oh! It's working... nevertheless, I was 5 second late to finish writing the answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you were trying to install 32bit packages on 64-bit Ubuntu. That is not necessary. Leave the `i386` part from the package name and just use `octave-image`.

Secondly, to be able to use `rgb2gray` function, you need to import the package where that function is defined. The package is `image` as revealed as par [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2012-05/msg00212.html). Also you need to load the package using `pkg load image` command first. Check this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939152/octave-rgb2gray-undefined-error) also.

Hope this will help.

Comment: @Sagittarius Glad it helped. Thanks to you too!